# Submit Google search after sending window to Google

Tags: javascript

I have managed to send a query to Google using window.location.href, but I can not figure out how to submit the Google search form so that I can see the results.

Here is my javascript code that send the window to Google with the query typed in the search-box, but how do I submit Google's form?

```
var query = "hello";
var firstPart = "http://google.com/?q=";
window.location.href = firstPart + query;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to submit it if you use this URL: "http://google.com/search?q=", in your code it would be:

```
var query = "hello";
var firstPart = "http://google.com/search?q=";
window.location.href = firstPart + query;
```